# Could not get value from text editor (jQuery Text Edior) with jQjery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question would like to ask, why could not I get value from bootstrap text editor ?

Here is html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <textarea name="textarea" class="jqte-test text-desc"></textarea>
  </div>
 </div
```

Here is my jquery code :

```
<script>
    var text_desc = $(".text-desc").val();
    $("#btn-for-text").on("click",function(){
        alert(text_desc);
    })
</script>
```

Note : I am using te jQuery Text Editor : [jqueryte.com](http://jqueryte.com/)

Comment: move your var inside of click.

Comment: Use `alert($(".text-desc").val());`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get the textarea value inside the click event function, never can get the currect value of textarea

```
<script>
$("#btn-for-text").on("click",function(){
    alert($(".text-desc").val());
})
</script>
```

Comment: Opps, was answer it at same time.